# angular 16 version module build failed

Tags: angular16

Hookwebpackerror :module build failed iam getting this error  can anyone let me know wt mistake I have done

when iam trying to run my project iam getting this error
module build failed iam getting this error  can anyone let me know wt mistake I have done